# How to add below mentioned Mapbox plugins to Android App

Tags: android, mapbox, turn-by-turn

I happen unable to add `LocationLayerPlugin` to my Android project and cannot find any documentation to demonstrate how. Also, I can't find `NavigationMapRoute` inside `package com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5`. Any help, please?

> EDIT:

That's my `build.gradle` below and when typing `LocationLayerPlugin`, Android Studio cannot resolve it.

```
    compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.1.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-services:2.1.3@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.3.1'
```

Comment: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-plugin-locationlayer/

Answer (score 1):

For the `LocationLayerPlugin` you can use it with two lines of code:

```
locationLayerPlugin = new LocationLayerPlugin(mapView, mapboxMap, locationEngine);
locationLayerPlugin.setLocationLayerEnabled(LocationLayerMode.TRACKING);
```

You'll need to make sure to also call the lifecycles in the appropriate methods `onStart` and `onStop`. If you are using with navigation and want to use location snapping to the route, you will need to pass in `null` for the locationEngine and than use `forceLocationUpdate` inside `onProgressChange`.

A few examples are [available here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/tree/master/plugins/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/testapp/activity/location) which show different ways to use the plugin. Documentation will be avliable soon once we release the first final version (currently just producing nightly builds).

For the NavigationMapRoute you'll need to make sure you are using the 0.4.0-snapshot of the Navigation SDK. you'll find it here `com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationMapRoute`